# Marshal struct array to xml without a parent tag

Tags: go

I am trying to marshal a go struct with an array into a *xml*. In this array I need to have a attribute for each element and a value. I do not need this to be inside a parent *xml* tag.

I have the code below.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type Person struct {
        XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"person"`
        Id        int      `xml:"id,attr"`
        FirstName string
    }

    a := &Person{
       Id: 13,
       FirstName: "John",
    }
    b := &Person{
       Id: 14,
       FirstName: "Doe",
    }
    x := []*Person{}
    x = append(x, a)
    x = append(x, b)

    enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.Indent("  ", "    ")
    if err := enc.Encode(x); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

It produces below output.

```
<person id="13">
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
</person>
<person id="14">
  <FirstName>Doe</FirstName>
</person>
```

But I need to make it as below.

```
<person id="13">John</person>
<person id="14">Doe</person>
```

Any help on this is much appreciated. Can I do this with go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `xml:",chardata"` tag to the `FirstName` filed:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type Person struct {
        XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"person"`
        ID        int      `xml:"id,attr"`
        FirstName string   `xml:",chardata"`
    }

    a := &Person{
        ID:        13,
        FirstName: "John",
    }
    b := &Person{
        ID:        14,
        FirstName: "Doe",
    }
    x := []*Person{}
    x = append(x, a)
    x = append(x, b)

    enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.Indent("  ", "    ")
    if err := enc.Encode(x); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<person id="13">John</person>
<person id="14">Doe</person>
```